# Getting List the blob in winRt application

Tags: c#, azure, windows-8

I would like to list blobs in a container. For desktop apps, the Azure Storage SDK provides the following method:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("myBlob"); 
container.ListBlobs();
```

However, using the [WinRT library](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/microsoft-azure-api/Services/Storage/Lib/RT) the method is absent (probably due to its blocking nature). What should I use instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to use `ListBlobsSegmentedAsync` function on the blob container to fetch the list of blobs. See the code below for example:

```
    CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("accountname", "accountkey"), true);
    var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var container = client.GetContainerReference("containername");
    BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
    string prefix = null;
    bool useFlatBlobListing = true;
    BlobListingDetails blobListingDetails = BlobListingDetails.All;
    int maxBlobsPerRequest = 10;
    List<IListBlobItem> blobs = new List<IListBlobItem>();
    do
    {
        var listingResult = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(prefix, useFlatBlobListing, blobListingDetails, maxBlobsPerRequest, continuationToken, null, null);
        continuationToken = listingResult.ContinuationToken;
        blobs.AddRange(listingResult.Results);
    }
    while (continuationToken != null);
```

Comment: Thanks! Work fine. Can you explain me, whan does it mean BlobContinuationToken and prefix?

Comment: Since blob storage service is an Internet based service, you don't get all the blobs in a blob container in a single request. Blob storage service returns you a maximum of 5000 blobs in a single request. If there're more than 5000 blobs in a blob container, the service returns a token using which you can fetch the next set of blobs. That's `BlobContainuationToken`. You would use `prefix` to get a partial list of blobs which starts with that particular `prefix`. For example, if you wish to fetch only the blobs which start with letter `"a"`, you would specify that as prefix. HTH.

Comment: can we use `string prefix = string.Empty` insted of `string prefix = null` ?

Comment: Yes. I think you can. Give it a try!

Comment: how would you list all blobs across all containers?

Answer (score 0):

Code modified to support Azure 2.2

```
CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("accountname", "accountkey"), true);
var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = client.GetContainerReference("containername");
BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
string prefix = null;
bool useFlatBlobListing = true;
BlobListingDetails blobListingDetails = BlobListingDetails.All;
int maxBlobsPerRequest = 10;
List<IListBlobItem> blobs = new List<IListBlobItem>();
do
{
    var listingResult = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(prefix, useFlatBlobListing, blobListingDetails, maxBlobsPerRequest, continuationToken, null, null);
    continuationToken = **listingResult.Result.ContinuationToken;**
    blobs.AddRange(**listingResult.Result.Results**);
}
while (continuationToken != null);
```

Comment: Is there any way to list blobs in descending order and how to make offset?