# Windows Universal App - Download all Blobs from Azure Container

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, win-universal-app

I have a Universal Windows app.

I am trying to download all blobs from an azure container when the app starts. This is my code:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        downloadblobs();
    }

public async void downloadblobs()
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageaccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("accountname", "accountkey"), true);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageaccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("ContainerName");

    //---------------------
    int fileName = 1;
    var client = storageaccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
    string prefix = null;
    bool useFlatBlobListing = true;
    BlobListingDetails blobListingDetails = BlobListingDetails.All;
    int maxBlobsPerRequest = 2500;
    List<IListBlobItem> blobs = new List<IListBlobItem>();
    do
    {
        var listingResult = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(prefix, useFlatBlobListing, blobListingDetails, maxBlobsPerRequest, continuationToken, null, null);
        continuationToken = listingResult.ContinuationToken;
        blobs.AddRange(listingResult.Results);
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"\NewImages\" + fileName + ".jpg"))
        {
            var blobReference = blobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(blobs.Uri);
            File downloadedFile = new File(blobReference + ".jpg");
            fileName++;
        }
    }
    while (continuationToken != null);
}
```

Im getting errors on two lines:

```
            var blobReference = blobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(blobs.Uri);
            File downloadedFile = new File(blobReference + ".jpg");
```

My errors are:

> ListBlobItem does not contain a definition of Uri.
>
> Cannot declare variable of static type File.

and

> Cannot create an instance of the static class file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enumerate the blobs in the container, with `container.listBlobsSegmentedAsync()`. The container reference doesn't just have a list of blobs automatically downloaded with it.

For reference, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobssegmentedasync.aspx).

Comment: I've tried to do this using both this link: https://ahmetalpbalkan.com/blog/azure-listblobssegmentedasync-listcontainerssegmentedasync-how-to/ and this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052813/getting-list-the-blob-in-winrt-application but cant get it working. Im completely lost!

Comment: You should edit your question to show what you tried, regarding `listBlobsSegmentedAsync()`. That way someone might be able to help. But bottom line: Your current implementation won't work since you never retrieve the blob list.

Comment: Do you have a link to a tutorial on sending blobs to win universal device? All the tut's online just tell you how to upload them to azure (Which I guess is the obvious direction for the blobs to travel, but I'm messing about with other stuff for the house and want to download them)

Comment: Tutorial recommendation questions are off-topic. And you've already found web pages that describe exactly how to retrieve a list of blobs from a container. And there are other stackoverflow questions which discuss enumeration (again, you've already found one such post). Let's not have a discussion here in comments.

Comment: I have edited the question as you suggested. Thanks. And thankyou for pointing me in the direction of Enumeration so I could try to get it working. Apologies for going off topic. Unfortunately enumerating the container doesnt seem to have achieved the ends. If you have any more guidance it would be appreciated also. Thanks again.