# List all containers and blobs

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am working on the Azure Local Development Storage with containers and blobs. I want to be able to display all my containers and blobs in a Listbox like a treeview of my Local Development Storage.
This is my code:

```
public List<string> ListContainer()
    {
        List<string> blobs = new List<string>();

        // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureStorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        //Get the list of the blob from the above container

        IEnumerable<CloudBlobContainer> containers = blobClient.ListContainers();

        foreach (CloudBlobContainer item in containers)
        {
            blobs.Add(string.Format("{0}", item.Uri.Segments[2]));
        }

        return blobs;
    }
```

Here i am displaying all my containers. I need to display all the blobs each container has, as well as the subfolders.

Comment: I posted an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35232885/272109) which explains what you need to do to enumerate blobs within a container. Your code doesn't enumerate blobs.

Answer (score 5):

You are iterating the containers, not the blobs in the containers. On each container you need to call [ListBlobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs.aspx).

Your code will look something like:

```
foreach (CloudBlobContainer item in containers)
    {
        foreach (IListBlobItem blob in item.ListBlobs()){
            blobs.Add(string.Format("{0}", blob.Uri.Segments[2]));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Correct, make sure the container has been created.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see you here. You dont need Listcontainer, you need to create container and list blob. **Firstly**, I already told you that you need to create a local contain for your local Storage, if not, where can store these files? You could use `container.createIfNotExists();` to new one, and upload file to its blob. Or download `azurestorageexplorer` from azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com, create local container in `azurestorageexplorer`.

This is my simple example:

```
   public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        ListBox1.DataSource =ListBlob("mycontainer");
        ListBox1.DataBind();

                  }
        public List<string> ListBlob(string folder)
        {
            List<string> blobs = new List<string>();

            // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(folder);

            // Loop over items within the container and output the length and URI.
            foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs(null, false))
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
                {
                    CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;

                    blobs.Add(string.Format("Block blob of length {0}: {1}", blob.Properties.Length, blob.Uri));

                }
                else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudPageBlob))
                {
                    CloudPageBlob pageBlob = (CloudPageBlob)item;

                    blobs.Add(string.Format("Page blob of length {0}: {1}", pageBlob.Properties.Length, pageBlob.Uri));

                }
                else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlobDirectory))
                {
                    CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)item;

                    blobs.Add(string.Format("Directory: {0}", directory.Uri)); ;
                }
            }
            return blobs;
        }

        protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox2.DataSource = ListBlob("mycontainer01");
            ListBox2.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Make sure set AutoPostBack="True" on ListBox1, please see more information form here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/. Keep contact if you have any question.